# Virtual interface

Tags: ufw, nic

I have a vps with a provider. It has 2 interfaces eth0 and eth0:1, each with one ip. One ip has normal web rules. The other one I want to restrict to only accept traffic to port 5001-5999

Regards
Anders Yuran

Comment: What is the question? Do you wan to make sure the UFW rules apply to both interfaces or do you wonder how to set different rules on each interface?

Comment: No that would be easy. I want to almost lock down the eth0:1  to only accept traffic from a few ports. The other interface has normal rules for a webserver

Comment: Best edit your question to add this. UFW rules have a `to` parameter for this. The difficulty is that most rules will have to specify the address.

Comment: Iedited the original